# Setting visibility of a textbox in MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC 3, razor view engine.
I want to set the visibility of a textbox at runtime as per the value in my viewmodel.

But the below code is not working.

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { visible = "false" })
</td>
```

Once above code starts working, I could place `@Model.EnableCompanyName` in place of hardcoded "false".

So please help me in rectifying the above code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will change the display type based on your bool Model.EnableCompanyName :)

Hope it helps!

```
@{
String displayMode = (Model.EnableCompanyName) ? "inline" : "none";
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { style = "display:" + displayMode + ";" })
}
```

Comment: Thx Chris. Just replace none with false in your first assignment & its working as expected.

Comment: Woops! School boy error lol. Updated answer to reflect that. :)

Answer (score 8):

It's nothing to do with razor as such. `visible` is not a valid attribute for an `input` element (which is what Html.TextBox will be generating).  You need

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { style = "display:none;" })
```

See this example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QxSpU/

Answer (score 3):

Updated:

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { style = Model.EnableCompanyName ? "display:inline" : "display:none" })
```

Comment: Hi,Even the hardcoding of false is not working. For Eg : @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { visible = "false" }) is not working.

Comment: so, you need to pass: new { style = "display:none" }

Comment: Next time try to specify more precisely what do you want. If u dont know how to hide DOM element this is another question. I just misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new {Style= Model.EnableCompanyName ? "visibility:visible" : "visibility:hidden"  })
```